# Como QDialog pode travar uma QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt

Estou implementando um programa de cadastro experimental, e fiz uma caso em que, se uma pessoa nada digita e tenta cadastrar esse dado vazio, ela abre uma `QDialog`, recebe o aviso e não completa o cadastro. Basicamente o código é:

**Classe MainWindow:**

```
#include "dado.h"
#include "dialog.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{

    [...]

    private slots:
        void on_botaoInserir_clicked();  

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    Dado *dado;

    Dialog dialog;
};
```

A classe `MainWindow` (janela principal do programa) possui um objeto do tipo `dialog` que é implementado pela classe `Dialog`:

**Classe Dialog:**

```
#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
    class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
     Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~Dialog();

     void setAviso(QString);

     QString getAviso();

private slots:
    void on_dialogButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};
```

Como fazer com que a `MainWindow` só se torne clicável após a janela de dialogo ser fechada? Pois mesmo com a janela de dialogo aberta ainda consigo mexer e realizar outro cadastro na janela principal.

**Trecho que abre o dialógo caso o usuário não informe os dados e tente cadastrar (localizado em `MainWindow`):**

```
    [...]

    ui->statusBar->showMessage("Pessoa adicionada.", SB_MESS_TIME);
}
else{

    dialog.setAviso("Digite um nome.");
    dialog.setFocus();
    dialog.show();
}

    [...]
```

Espero que alguem diga uma maneira de "travar" a janela principal enquanto o objeto `dialog` acima estiver executando a função `show()`.

Comment: Acredito que isso ocorra na instanciação de `dialog`. Por favor, poste o código para que possamos ajudá-lo :)

Comment: A instanciação está no terceiro código. Que utiliza um objeto dialog criado com base no primeiro código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se entendi bem, o comportamento que você deseja pode ser obtido alterando a propriedade [`WindowModality`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowModality-prop) da sua `QDialog`:

```
dialog.setAviso("Digite um nome.");
dialog.setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
dialog.show();
```

O código acima vai exibir o diálogo na tela e impedir qualquer interação com todas as outras janelas do programa, até que o diálogo seja fechado.

Outro possível comportamento é utilizar `Qt::WindowModal`, dessa maneira apenas a janela responsável pelo diálogo (no caso a `MainWindow`) ficará inacessível.

```
dialog.setAviso("Digite um nome.");
dialog.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
dialog.show();
```

Porém é necessário que você defina quem é a janela responsável pelo diálogo, alterando o "construtor" da sua `MainWindow` para algo como:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    dialog(this) // atenção nessa linha
{
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: Não seria mais fácil colocar o `QWidget* parent` como a `MainWindow`?

Comment: Era exatamente essa solução que estava procurando, obrigado!